# Number of shared memory users

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, ipc, shared-memory

Let's assume I have a shared memory, created via mmap, or shm_open or MapViewOfFile. I would want to know how many processes (or even better threads) have right now the memory opened.
Is there some function to find out how many users a file descriptor/handle has right now ? or something similar.

Background:
I try to make a plug-in peer to peer communication in one computer. Plug-ins are Audio VST, and I need this for time syncing. My idea was to use shared memory in order they would be able to find themselves. (and they indeed can be launched in different processes). But for proper operation I need to know the number of actual plug-ins which have the shared memory opened. Just increasing the reference counter inside the memory will not work because the plug-in's process can be crashed at any moment, so the reference counter will not be decreased. The same is true for semaphores.

OSes of interest are Windows and Mac OS X.
Probably the task can be solved via using "server" or coordination process, but it's really bad for a plug-in.. i.e. it will need an installer and it will be hard to explain users why they need a system service for the plug-in.

Comment: Windows and OS X are *very* different operating systems, with very different shared-memory subsystems, process-management characteristics, and threading implementations.  Your question would probably be too broad even if you specified an OS; it is *definitely* too broad when you do not.

Comment: I'd be happy to find out at least particular solution; then if I'm lucky I will find it for other OS by association. or question like "is there a windows|osx replacement for a <function>"

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that your question is too broad.  It is not suitable for SO in its present form.

Comment: IMHO it won't be better if I put two separate question... why you think it's too broad. will it be too broad to ask how to open a file in OS for example ? I agree there will be two different ways depending on OS

Comment: It won't be better as two separate questions because, as I already said, even those questions would probably still be too broad.  Additionally, it might not serve *your personal interests* as well to pose two separate questions, but that, frankly, is of no consequence whatever.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I don't see how the question "How to get the number of users of a shared memory block" is too broad.

Comment: I'm done.  I commented in the first place only out of courtesy.  In the end, the community will decide.

Comment: POSIX has an `ipcs` utility that does exactly what you asked, I'm not sure if it's available on OSX, but it should be.